# I'm frequently getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 23" in a php file

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

I'm frequently getting parse error, syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 23. Please help me out with this. Here is my code...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
If(empty($_REQUEST['name'])){
print<<<HERE
Please enter your name:
<form>
<input type = "text" name = "name">
<input type = "submit">
</form>
HERE; }
else {
print "Hello $_REQUEST[name]";}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Line 27 is

```
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using `print<<<HERE...HERE;` just close the PHP tag and reopen it when you're done with the HTML.

Comment: But, this is what given in the php reference book.

Comment: _What_ PHP reference book? Just because someone wrote a book, doesn't mean it's going to be the bible of PHP, or the end-all-be-all of how PHP should be written.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: @j08691 It's probably what they're referring to, but if OP truly read that fully, they would see the big yellow box that says "**Warning**: It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;)." etc. etc.

Comment: check for whitespace after the HERE;. In other words, there is probably extra white space. Just put your cursor right after the semi-colon and left-click and drag. If anything get's highlighted, delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the HERE statement, rather than opening and closing PHP tags as suggested elsewhere, the problem is you have data after the closing HERE. Just move the closing bracket, after the closing HERE, to the next line.  This code runs as expected:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(empty($_REQUEST['name'])){
print<<<HERE
Please enter your name:
<form>
<input type = "text" name = "name">
<input type = "submit">
</form>
HERE;

}
else {
print "Hello $_REQUEST[name]";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ArjunTamble This code works. If you're still having trouble you need to give more detail than _'it isn't running'_.

Comment: I mean, it still shows "parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of line" even after following your code.

Comment: Unable to catch the fault. I still don't know why it is showing so.

Comment: I even tried replacing print "..."; with <<<HERE...HERE; It shows Synatx error, unexpected text.

Comment: I'm just a fresher programmer in php studying on my own. I did'nt face any problem as this till now. But, this seems to be very annoying.

Comment: Mke sure there is no white space between the last HERE and the semicolon. Go to the phpfiddle link I created and click run. It will run. Then you can copy the code there and paste it into your editor. There is nothing wrong with that code. If you are still facing that exact same problem, it is whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The final bracket of "if" should be in new line.

```
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(empty($_REQUEST['name'])){
print<<<HERE
Please enter your name:
<form>
<input type = "text" name = "name">
<input type = "submit">
</form>
HERE;
} else {
print "Hello " .$_REQUEST["name"];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Suggest: print $_REQUEST out of print instruction or echo.

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
If(empty($_REQUEST['name'])){
print <<<HERE
Please enter your name:
<form>
<input type = "text" name = "name">
<input type = "submit">
</form>
HERE;
} else {
    print "Hello $_REQUEST[name]"; 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apart from not fixing the problem, what is this supposed to do?

Comment: settle down dude.  had a bad indent in there

Comment: Even after you fixed the indent this doesn't explain what the problem was. I note that there are already two other answers with the same solution and they include some explanation.